# new project not showing up Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Was recently added to a new firebase project via the web interface but it isn't showing up in firebase list. I can see the project in my firebase console. I've tried restarting my terminal, logging out/in, and doing firebase use, but no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Two things come to mind: 1) make sure you actually created the project under the account you're using in the CLI, 2) if you have many projects, the CLI may initially show a subset, user your cursor keys to move and see other projects.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what it is, is that you must enable Firestore (and/or perhaps Storage) on the firebase.google.com website. i.e. configure your project first, then when you choose features, e.g., firestore, storage, etc in Step 1 of firebase-cli `firebase init` projects with those features enabled show up in Step 2 "choose project"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 24 hrs, the project finally showed up in my list. Turns out there's just an extremely long delay if you're not the owner of the project.

Comment: Hi, I'm having similar [problem](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1098) but my one not listing at all. Do you meant we just need to wait awhile after seeing `? Which project do you want to add? (Use arrow keys)`

Comment: Hope you are right because if not I am in big trouble tomorrow

Answer (score 11):

`firebase-init` first asks which features you wish to use, e.g. `database`, `firestore`, `storage`, etc.

If you choose `firestore` but have not yet enabled Firestore in your newly created Firebase project via firebase.google.com website, that project will not show up as a project option.

So, before running firebase-cli, enable all the features you want via the website first, ...before chosing those features in step 1 of `firebase init`.

Once you've enabled Firestore, for example, your project will now show up.

Comment: I don't know why but it happens, when the default delay is too much for you, To enable database is a good option to see the project in the list and link fast.

Answer (score 8):

You can select your project if you know the project id:

```
firebase use --add
```

That will select the project, so when you type "firebase init" will not show the select project option but take you to the next step

Answer (score 8):

There is now a --project option you can use with firebase init to choose the project.

```
firebase init --project <projectId>
```

Answer (score 2):

While following the firebase init steps, use the **[don't setup a default project]** option.

Then use firebase use `--add projectId` to add the project.

Answer (score 1):

So recently I changed my password, and was still logged into my firebase account, I did `firebase logout` and then tried `firebase login` again, and this time the `firebase use --add` command worked

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else: a firebase project is just a firebase-enabled Google Cloud Platform project.

You can create a GCP project but it won't appear in the firebase CLI until you visit console.firebase.google.com and enable firebase for your GCP project of choice.

Then

```
firebase use --add your_google_cloud_platform_project_id
```

Should detect your project.

Answer (score 0):

When firebase init asks you to choose a project from the list just check **[don't setup a default project]** and after the installation you can manually add the project to the **.firebaserc** file as shown below.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "your-project-id"
  }
}
```

You can check the id's of your projects with the command **firebase list**.
It'll also show the current project.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me.

Get the Project Id from firebase console. e.g. myproject-2233

On Firebase CLI run below command 
$ firebase -P myproject-2233

Next Select the features you want to add e.g. Web Hosting
Next Select "Don't Setup a default project"
Give the public folder name

It worked only after choosing "Don't Setup a default project"